# How to get scp version?

Tags: scp, version

How to get `scp` version?

Already tried:

```
$ scp --version
scp: unknown option -- -
usage: scp [-346ABCOpqRrsTv] [-c cipher] [-D sftp_server_path] [-F ssh_config]
           [-i identity_file] [-J destination] [-l limit]
           [-o ssh_option] [-P port] [-S program] source ... target

$ man scp | grep version
<nothing>
```

Does it mean that `scp` has no version?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `ssh -V` to see what release of OpenSSH the `ssh` and associated client tools are from.  The installed version of `ssh`, `scp` and `sftp` will all be from the same release of OpenSSH.

On my OpenBSD system:

```bash
$ ssh -V
OpenSSH_9.0, LibreSSL 3.5.2
```

On a nearby Ubuntu machine:

```bash
$ ssh -V
OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.5, OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020
```

Comment: Until they aren't. <g> although I don't think mismatched scp matters much as it's going to run ssh scp ... to handle the connection.

Comment: @Joshua In instances where you've managed to install `scp` and `ssh` from different releases of OpenSSH, you are on your own. In such cases, you have a broken package and would need to do some administrational maintenance anyway.